# When you select a text on inline code highlight usages

Tags: feature-request

As the title states that would be nice to find usages on given code block. Please see below example.

I just pick a question right asked now:

[Java reading html file storaged in a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331965/java-reading-html-file-storaged-in-a-jar)

Lets take a look code block:

```
 // TODO - failed to open in file when running in JAR
File filename = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/resource-uk.html").getFile());

try {
    URL url = new URL( "file:///"+filename);
    html = new JEditorPane( url );
    html.setEditable( false );
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(html);
    topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    html.addHyperlinkListener( this );
}
catch( MalformedURLException e )
{
    System.out.println( "Malformed URL: " + e );
}
catch( IOException e )
{
    System.out.println( "IOException: " + e );
}
```

i.e. I want to see where the **fileName** used in this code block.So what would help me that I select the text I want to see usages and all usages will have a different color. Do you think it is possible?

**EDIT****: I have added small script example into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1gL56td/)

Comment: There are plenty of other things SO could spend there dev time on when a simple find works or you can copy and paste the code into an IDE.

Comment: @NathanOliver well it still makes it a feature request isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in your browser?

[image]

---

My point is that this would be a pretty big thing to implement site-wide for something that not a lot of people would use. Similar search functionality is already built in to most modern browsers or operating systems so I don't see a real use for this.

In my opinion, syntax highlighting and user search are sufficient enough.

Comment: I think not that hard to implement, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3545105/706695

Comment: A quick jFiddle showing the selection is **very** different to overriding syntax highlighting scripts, multiple css files, ajax calls, limiting selections to defined `<pre>` blocks etc. and *then* having to implement that across an entire site without it affecting *anything* else. So yes, it *is* that hard to implement. Not to mention there will be a whole design/test/UAT cycle to go through before it can even go live which uses a lot of human resource, and ultimately that is time that costs money.

Comment: I dont want to be opposite or straigh but: why ajax calls it is a client code? it is <code> not <pre> so no alternative selector needs to be handled. You dont implement entire site you include java script in your header. But of course it can be big that there can be things I dont think and if you include UAT cycle  beside of implementation you need resources too